# How to define constructor in class with struct as data member in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor

I made a struct as a data member in class. Now, I want to make a constructor to which I will pass my data members. How can I pass struct in constructor.

I wrote this code but it's not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
class circle
{
    private:
        struct center
        { 
            int xcord;
            int ycord;
        };
        struct center cordinate;
        float radius;
    public:
        circle()
        {
            cordinate.xcord=0;
            cordinate.ycord=0;
            radius=0;
        };
        circle(int x, int y, float r) : cordinate.xcord(x), cordinate.ycord(y), radius(r)
        {};
        void showdata()
        {
            cout<<"Center(x,y) = ("<<cordinate.xcord<<","<<cordinate.ycord<<")"<<endl;
            cout<<"Radius = "<<radius<<endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
    circle c1;
    c1.showdata();
}
```

Or if I wrote it like this, it still don't work.

```
circle(int x, int y, float r) : center.xcord(x), center.ycord(y), radius(r)
        {};
```

or

```
circle(int x, int y, float r) : center.cordinate.xcord(x), center.cordinate.ycord(y), radius(r)
        {};
```

How can I pass struct to constructor?

Comment: Tip, when you say "this doesn't work" or similar - say what you expected to happen and what actually happened, along with any error messages or relevant information :) This will make your questions better received because it's clearer what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize the `cordinate` member like this:

```
circle(int x, int y, float r) : cordinate{x, y}, radius{r} {}
```

Also, your default constructor can be simplified to:

```
circle() : circle(0, 0, 0) {}
```

which delegates to the 3-argument constructor. Even better, just use in class member initializers for all the fields:

```
struct center
{ 
   int xcord = 0;
   int ycord = 0;
} cordinate;
float radius = 0;
```

and then you can default the default constructor:

```
circle() = default;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MzWE9a).

Comment: Better to assign default values in class declaration and `= default` the default constructor. Also, get rid of the extra semi-colon after the parameterized constructor. https://godbolt.org/z/dsnYo1

Comment: @sweenish Good points, added to the answer, thanks.